# Acessing a Variable outside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Could someone help me with this question. 
I am trying to understand how can I access the variable "new_name_input" inside one of my functions. The goal it's just to set my variable with the name choosen. I would be glad if someone could explain it to me or/and show me how can I make it.

See code below.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.names=
    [
    {nome:'Renan'},
    {nome:'Geraldo'}
    ];
    $scope.newNames=
    [
    {nome:'Fernando'},
    {nome:'José'}
    ];
    
    $scope.transfer=function(novoNome,place){
    alert(novoNome.nome);
    this.place = novoNome.nome;
    }
    
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 
<div style='border:1px solid black;display:inline;margin:10px 10px 10px 10px' 
ng-repeat='name in names'>
<input type='text' ng-model='new_name_input'/>
<div>
<p ng-click='transfer(new_name,new_name_input)' ng-repeat='new_name in newNames'>
  {{new_name.nome}}
</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

When I click on the names written, the names does not get added in the textbox. I am wondering how can I do it without remove the ng-repeat from the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I'm following your question completely, but is this what you're attempting to do? Basically, you need a "." in the `ng-model` in order to have two-way bindings work with primitives. I used `ng-init` to create a new object to achieve that, but I wonder if you mean to get the new value back into the `name` object? If so, you can drop the `ng-init` and just pass the `name` object into the transfer method instead.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.names=
    [
    {nome:'Renan'},
    {nome:'Geraldo'}
    ];
    $scope.newNames=
    [
    {nome:'Fernando'},
    {nome:'José'}
    ];
    
    $scope.transfer=function(novoNome,nameVm){
    alert(novoNome.nome);
    nameVm.new_name_input= novoNome.nome;
    }
    
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 
<div style='border:1px solid black;display:inline;margin:10px 10px 10px 10px' 
ng-repeat='name in names' ng-init="nameVm = {}">
<input type='text' ng-model='nameVm.new_name_input'/>
<div>
<p ng-click='transfer(new_name,nameVm)' ng-repeat='new_name in newNames'>
  {{new_name.nome}}
</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Adam, it was exactly what i am trying to do.

Comment: You added an array on the first ng-repeat, I think it works fine for me. Now I am going to understand, at least try, the solution you came up. Thank you!

Comment: @RenanCostaSerra, great! And welcome to Stack Overflow. As a tip, it's customary to mark the answer that best answers your question as the "accepted" answer.

Comment: Oh, and that's an object that I added, not an array. :) I updated the comment in my answer to reflect this.